# Polars: Create column with fixed value from variable

Tags: python-polars

I have scrubbed the `polars` docs and cannot see an example of creating a column with a fixed value from a variable.  Here is what works in `pandas`:

```
df['VERSION'] = version
```

Thx

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [`polars.lit`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.lit.html)

```py
import polars as pl

version = 6
df = df.with_columns(pl.lit(version).alias('VERSION'))
```

Comment: Here's some documentation on the `lit` expression: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.lit.html

Comment: Thanks @cbilot for the quick response.  Trying to migrate all of pandas code for extract, transform and load into database to polars.

Comment: `with_columns()` is now the correct method, `with_column` will throw an error.